# SQL in statement for last data

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with `IN` statement. I have two tables.

Table_1

```
id    | active_device_id| device_status
0     |  1              | 1
1     |  2              | 1
2     |  3              | 1
```

Table_2

```
id | device_id | value
0  |          1| 10
1  |          2| 20
2  |          3| 30
3  |          1| 40
4  |          2| 50
5  |          5| 60
```

I want to get last value of device from Table_2 according to Table_1

So I use this

```
select * 
from Table_2
where device_id in (
    select active_device_id
    from Table_1
    where device_status=1
 )
 order by id desc
```

This query get all records for devices. But I want to get last one record for each device. Shortly I want to this

```
id | device_id| value
4  |         2| 50
3  |         1| 40
2  |         3| 30
```

Can you help me for this situation?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `IN` statement is going to return all records where that value matches, which will end up returning all values from Table_2 except for id=5 (device_id of 5 isn't in Table_1).  Also, the way you are using the `IN` statement is better handled with an `INNER JOIN`.

The better way to accomplish what you are after is using a self join.  Basically, I'm joining Table_2 back to itself and only returning the highest "id" value in the table for each row that matches device_id.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table_2 AS t2
INNER JOIN Table_1 AS t1 ON t2.device_id = t1.active_device_id
  AND t1.device_status = 1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2self ON t2.device_id=t2self.device_id AND t2self.id>t2.id
WHERE t2self.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t2.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports window functions (as it should by the way), there is a slightly simpler approach:

```
select id, device_id, value from 
(
select row_number() over (partition by t2.device_id order by t2.id desc) as rownum,
t2.*
from table_2 t2 join table_1 t1 on t2.device_id = t1.active_device_id and t1.device_status = 1
) temp where rownum = 1
```

However, I am upvoting Ashley Lee's answer, as I think it provides a very important **ANSI-SQL** workaround for other DBMSs as MySql, where it is customary to use variables to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Your answer **is** ANSI SQL.

Comment: I know :-), still MySql does not support this (as it should), so the other answer provides an ANSI workaround.